# What Permissions Necessary to Run Google Batch Job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, batch-processing, identity-management

Trying to run a container as a batch job. I have already pushed the corresponding image to the artefact registry.

But whenever I try to create a job via the BatchAPI web interface, the page fails to load, and I get an error message saying something like

```
There was an error while loading the page. Please try again. It may be a browser or network issue.
```

I have tried the usual, like logging out, logging in, clearing browser cache etc. Nothing helped.

Also, my administrator has granted me the Batch Job Editor permission (among others). Is that enough to create and run a batch job?

Comment: Are you compute engine admin (or editor) also? Is the compute engine API activated?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/create-run-basic-job#api), To create a job, ask your administrator to grant you the following IAM roles:

> - [Batch Job Editor](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#batch.jobsEditor) (roles/batch.jobsEditor) on the project
> - [Service Account User](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#iam.serviceAccountUser) (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) on the [job's service account](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/create-run-job-custom-service-account#create-job-service-account), which by default is the [default Compute Engine service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#default_service_account)

Also try  accessing it through Incognito window and delete your web cache cookies.

As mentioned in comment by  guillaume blaquiere, Make sure Compute Engine API is enabled, check  project's activity logs through the Logs Explorer in the Google Cloud Console.

From the console, go to the Logging page.
When in the Logs Explorer, select and filter  your resource type from  the first drop-down list.Select `compute.googleapis.com/activity_log` to see Compute Engine activity logs.